# Android tab bar view overlapping?

Tags: android, tabbar

My question is regarding android tab bar. I have created tab bar in a separate activity and on default first tab view, I am showing layout of an activity. Now when I use tab bar in any other activity, the activity's layout overlapped the tab bar view. Error in catlog is "couldn't save which view to show...". What is the way to show tab bar view along with the activity's view. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If you re taking about an action bar overlapping with the view; you can add `android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"` to your layout to "push" the view down under the action bar.

Comment: It helped to solve custom view overlapping support toolbar. Standard components does not need it, strange.